# How to import themes to React without copy-paste?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, themes, web-frontend

I recently started to work with React and I want to use an admin template. I am looking for a way to import the styles from theme to React components. I am using [Keen Admin Theme](https://keenthemes.com/keen/)

Theme includes all necessary html, js and sass files. Various tutorials suggest copying and pasting the html code inside the component but I am looking for a more practical way rather than copying and pasting because JSX requires additional changes on html, furthermore I think it is not a good practice.

So what I am looking for is similar to Angular's approach, so I can pass the html file directly to the component.

Angular's approach:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-overview',
  templateUrl: './component-overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-overview.component.css']
})
```

If there is no such option what is the recommended way of using out-of-box themes in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to write it yourself to avoid copying pasting. Or find the components that are of React or Angular (as per your requirements)